# Prove that function $f(x)=\frac{27}{\sin(x)}+\frac{64}{\cos(x)}$ has a minimum value but no maximum value at $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

By differentiation I got the derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{64\sin^3(x)-27\cos^3(x)}{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}$$
and then got the zero of derivative
$$x=\arctan(\frac{3}{4})$$
insert x to f(x)=y get the "minimum" value
$$f_{min}(x)=125$$
but I don't know how to prove this value is exactly the minimum not the maximum, noticed that the denominator of $f'(x)$ always be positive, then I only need to prove
$$64\sin^3(x)-27\cos^3(x)<0,\: \text{if}\ 0<x<\arctan(3/4)$$
$$64\sin^3(x)-27\cos^3(x)>0,\: \text{if}\ 0<x<\arctan(3/4)$$
and I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind :), guess this is the benefit of rewriting, forces one to think deeper and may inspire oneself to dig out the answer. By the way, if any one get a better answer, please post it, I'll read it, Thanks!

---

case one: $x<arctan(3/4)$
$$
\begin{align}
64sin^3(x)-27cos^3(x)&<0\\
tan(x)&<\frac{3}{4}\\
\end{align}
$$
this is obviously true because $tan(x)$ is monotonic increasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

case two is similar to case one.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of the expression is $\infty$ when $x=0$ or any other angle in periodicity. This means that either of the denominators has to be $0$. Since when $$x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}2\right)$$ the denominator i.e. $\operatorname{sin}x$ or $\operatorname{cos}x$ can never be $0$ therefore the answer that you got by differentiating $(125)$ is the minimum.